# Force Stream::filter method to fail compile time when Predicate<? super Object> is passed rather than Predicate<? super T>

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm playing around with predefined Identity filters for use with the stream api. Unfortunately I'm unable to properly return a generic predicate that is compliant with the [stream api documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)).

According to the de-compiler here is the `Stream::filter` definition:

```
public interface Stream<T> extends BaseStream<T, Stream<T>> {

    Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> var1);
```

I'm facing the issue with any Java version that has Streams support (8~15). The issue has nothing to do with my implementation. This code actually is enough in order to reproduce it:

```
        Collection<String> result = Stream.of("A", "B", "C")
                                          .filter(new Object()::equals)
                                          .filter(Integer.valueOf(-1)::equals)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Here, two predicates are applied where both of them aren't `<? super String>` compliant...

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50328387/2185630) this behavior seems to be strange...

How should I prevent users of my library from filtering on `ServerState` by random Object equality check, etc...?

Ideally I would like to always return proper Predicate<? super T> unfortunately that is not backed up by any compile time error...

Using a linter is not a solution in that case.

Even though I know how *lower bounded wildcards* work what I've been missing is that a `Predicate<? super Integer>` could be successfully casted to `Predicate<? super String>`.

Where:

```
Predicate<? super String> stringPredicate = (Predicate<? super String>)Filters.is_tClass(Integer.class, 4);
Predicate<? super Server> serverPredicate = (Predicate<? super Server>)Filters.is_comparable(5);

Collection<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
                                   .filter((Predicate<? super Integer>)stringPredicate)
                                   .filter((Predicate<? super Integer>)serverPredicate)
                                   .filter(Filters.is(new Object()))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

results in `[]` empty resultset.

Here is what I have so far, but not happy with any of it:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
                                           //.filter(Filters.is_tClass(Integer.class, 4)) // enforce user to provide target class
                                           //.filter(Filters.is_comparable(5)) // use only Comparable
                                           .filter(Filters.is(new Server())) // fail runtime with custom exception
                                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static class Server {
    }

    private static class Filters {

        private static <T> Predicate<? super T> is(T other) {

            return t -> {

                // simple class equality check - error prone!
                Class<?> tClass = t.getClass();
                Class<?> otherClass = other.getClass();

                if (!tClass.equals(otherClass)) {

                    throw new RuntimeException(
                        String.format("Check equality for [%s ? %s] seems odd. Can not continue...", tClass, otherClass));
                }
                return t.equals(other);
            };
        }

        static <T> Predicate<? super T> is_tClass(Class<T> tClass, T other) {

            return is(other);
        }

        static <T extends Comparable<T>> Predicate<? super T> is_comparable(T other) {

            return is(other);
        }
    }
}
```

Methods with names of the type `is_*` did not exist before posting the sample in here and therefor will be removed...

**EDIT**

Even though I know how *lower bounded wildcards* work what I've been missing is that a `Predicate<? super Integer>` could be successfully casted to `Predicate<? super String>`.

Where:

```
Predicate<? super String> stringPredicate = (Predicate<? super String>)Filters.is_tClass(Integer.class, 4);
Predicate<? super Server> serverPredicate = (Predicate<? super Server>)Filters.is_comparable(5);

Collection<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
                                   .filter((Predicate<? super Integer>)stringPredicate)
                                   .filter((Predicate<? super Integer>)serverPredicate)
                                   .filter(Filters.is(new Object()))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

results in `[]` empty resultset.

Comment: Read about [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super#:~:text=tl%3Bdr%3A%20%22PECS%22,use%20either%20extends%20or%20super%20.) to learn about generic type parameters and uper/lower bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here, two predicates are applied where both of them aren't <? super String> compliant

It's not true: the 2 predicates do consume an `Object`, which is the parent of `String`.

`<? super String>` must not be confused with `<? extends String>`.